# Can i use Microsoft Fakes to "shim" .net function calls in a 3rd party executable?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, testing, microsoft-fakes

MS Fakes can be used to redirect function calls to stub or shim functions in your vs project which you have the src code to but i was wondering if it can be used for debugging purposes to shim functions in a 3rd party exe? On the description page, it says that shim works at runtime so there shouldn't be any reason that i can't use it on 3rd party executables right?

Comment: Typically, a shim only works with weak linking, not static or dynamic linking. Take a loop at OS X. It uses weak linking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is, as it seems to be, "Can I shim functions in a library I'm referencing in my project?" the answer is undoubtedly yes.

That's the whole point. Let's say you include microsoft's prism dlls: Fakes allows you to shim  the obscure components (say, regionmanager) allowing you to 'pretend' that they work, isolating your business logic from external calls.

You should be doing this in a unit test, so that on every check in you can be sure that the code still works. If you require one time debugging, you're probably doing something wrong, and risking having to do it again in the future, even passing it on for someone else to try to learn and repeat in the future.

If you're asking whether or not you can do this outside a test, I can't answer that.